# In MongoDB, does a lock apply to a collection, a database, or a server?

Tags: mongodb, locking

In a MongoDB server, there may be multiple databases, and each database can have multiple collections, and a collection can have multiple documents.

Does a lock apply to a collection, a database, or a server?

I asked this question because when designing MongoDB database, I want to determine what is stored in a database and what is in a collection. My data can be partitioned into different parts, and I hope to be able to move a part from a MongoDB server to a filesystem, without being hindered by the lock that applies to another part, so I wish to store the parts of data in a way that different parts have different locks.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what is available to me on a server machine. I haven't heard of the version yet. How specifically does it depend on the version?

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/

Basically, it's global / database / collection.

But with some specific storage engines, it can lock at document level too, for instance with WiredTiger (only with Mongo 3.0+)

Comment: Thanks. How can I modify or set up the granularity of locks? Tried to search for that in the link, but didn't know where.